# DB2 SQL If statement inside select and inner join

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a simple query. I am doing a simple select (see below). It works now I want to do an inner join to another table and also do an if statement inside. I have been searching the web and cannot find what I am looking for.

I basically want to join into the item master table and if it is type 'E' do something else do something.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
EXEC SQL Declare RSCURSOR cursor for
    SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM HPO A
INNER JOIN IIML01 B on A.PPROD = B.IPROD
IF B.IITYP <> 'E';
PCMT = B.IDESC;
ELSE;
PCMT = A.PCMT ;
WHERE PORD = :PON AND PLINE = :LIN;

EXEC SQL  Open RSCURSOR;

EXEC SQL SET RESULT SETS Cursor RSCURSOR;

IF SQLSTATE = '00000';
  RSL = '00';
ELSEIF SQLSTATE = '02000';
  RSL = '10';
ELSE;
  RSL = '20';
ENDIF;
```

This is what I have in RPG fixed:

```
     C     PPROD         CHAIN     IPI100IM                           99
     C     *IN99         IFEQ      '0'
     C
     C     IITYP         IFNE      'E'
     C                   EVAL      RS(CNT).PCMT = IDESC                         
     C                   ELSE
     C                   EVAL      RS(CNT).PCMT = PCMT                          
     C                   ENDIF
```

Comment: Look for CASE WHEN <> THEN <> ELSE <> END statements

Comment: Can you add more detail to this question?  What have you tried?  Are you asking how to do a simple join?  If not, why didn't you add the join to the question?

Comment: I have not tried nothing because I don't know where to start.

Comment: I modified the code above. I know its wrong but that is what I am trying to do. I hope this helps more?

Comment: Can you please give us sample inputs and outputs that you are expecting?  That would really help to clarify the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not totally clear, but I think you want this:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM HPO A
INNER JOIN IIML01 B on A.PPROD = B.IPROD 
  AND CASE WHEN B.IITYP <> 'E' THEN B.IDESC ELSE A.PCMT END = PCMT
WHERE PORD = :PON AND PLINE = :LIN;
```

---

Based on the comment you want something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN B.IITYP <> 'E' THEN B.IDESC ELSE A.PCMT END AS PCMT, A.*, B.*
FROM HPO A
INNER JOIN IIML01 B on A.PPROD = B.IPROD 
WHERE PORD = :PON AND PLINE = :LIN;
```

Comment: It only returns A.PCMT value. Should the case be in the select?

Comment: @Tretiak You still need to clarify what you are trying to do.  I think Hogan's solution is correct given what we have.  A join will select only records where the fields are equal to each other.  Is the join only supposed to be on the `PPROD = IPROD` fields with every record returned or should the `IF` statement be part of the join as well?

Comment: @Tretiak -- I don't know you said you want it to join on different columns based on the IITYP column -- this is what I did.

Comment: I am trying to do a join on the item master table. If the IITYP field value is not equal to 'E' then over write the PCMT (PO table) field with the description field in the Item master, otherwise just use PCMT value. I hope this helps

Comment: @Tretiak -- ok I put it in select, you probably don't want to use `*` for the other tables in this case but specify every column.

Comment: This how it looks on fixed format.       C     PPROD         CHAIN     IPI100IM                           99
     C     *IN99         IFEQ      '0'
     C
     C     IITYP         IFNE      'E'
     C                   EVAL      RS(CNT).PCMT = IDESC                         Description
     C                   ELSE
     C                   EVAL      RS(CNT).PCMT = PCMT                          Description
     C                   ENDIF

Comment: I added the RPG fixed code I have in the original question. Hogan, I tried your modified code and I get the same result. It seems like it returns the A.PCMT value everytime when in reality if IITYP <> 'E' it should return description from that table.

Comment: OK, I got it to work, when I removed the * and use actual columns. Thanks everyone with your extreme patience!!!